# How to check network type (data class, i.e. EDGE/3G/LTE) for mobile broadband under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, mobile-broadband-api

I use the mobile broadband api ([mobile broadband api in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269(v=vs.85).aspx)) to handle 3G/LTE modem connections under windows 7.

Depends on used hardware (LTE-Stick or built in modem) I get different behavior, when I want to check the current connection generation.

In some cases I get for few seconds correct data class (i.e. 3G) and then for the most of the time the "custom" data class [MBN_DATA_CLASS_CUSTOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323219(v=vs.85).aspx).

So I want to try a different solution, mayby there is a problem with the modem and the MBN-API.

I know about the `NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()` but this works only under Windows 8 and above ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539251/windows-10-uwp-c-how-to-check-network-type-edge-3g-lte-not-only-cellular)).

My question is: Is there any other API / Class that I can use to get the data class?